# Background accessing microphone in android

Tags: java, android, service, background-process, microphone

I am developing an android application. I want to access the microphone in Background means when the screen is off. I don't want to record the sounds. What I need is to make an event to trigger if the amplitude exceeds some value. How can I achieve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to start an Activity with a **Service**.

In the service, create a [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) object.

This class has a few methods for amplitude (one of them being `getMaxAmplitude()`). You can use that along with a little bit of math to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'l give it a try. I could heard that the API don't allow us to access microphone while in background.